# Split Alphanumeric string using presto

Tags: presto

I am using Presto SQL to split an alphanumeric string which looks like this
AB1234CD to AB1234
JA4567EF.8 to JA4567

I am trying to remove the alphabets and anything after the alphabets at the end of the string.

Comment: It would be better to share some code or the command you've used.

Answer (score 1):

Based on examples you provided, you want to retain

- leading letters
- digits after leading letters

discarding everything afterwards.

For this [`regexp_extract`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_extract) is a perfect fit.

```sql
presto:default> SELECT regexp_extract('AB1234CD', '^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*');
 _col0
--------
 AB1234
(1 row)
```

(tested on Presto 322)

Answer (score 0):

After seeing you examples and query there can be two possible solutions:

1. Extract string starting with alphabets and followed by numbers
2. Extract a six length string .

The following part of the query is used for generating test data, you can replace it by your select query.

```
  WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT CAST(ROW('ABC12345DE') AS ROW(id VARCHAR)) AS data)
```

*For first solution there are two possibilities  either to extract first occurrence or extract all the possible string:*

#### Extract first possible string

```
  with dataset AS (
  SELECT CAST(ROW('AB1234CDE') AS ROW(id VARCHAR)) AS data) 
  SELECT regexp_extract(data.id,'[a-zA-Z]*[1-9]*') AS str from dataset
```

#### Extract all possible strings

```
  with dataset AS (
  SELECT CAST(ROW('AB1234CDE123') AS ROW(id VARCHAR)) AS data) 
  SELECT regexp_extract_all(data.id,'[a-zA-Z]*[1-9]*') AS str from dataset
```

*For Second solution:*

#### Extract 6 length string

```
  with dataset AS (
  SELECT CAST(ROW('AB1234CDE') AS ROW(id VARCHAR)) AS data )
  select substr(data.id, 1, 6)  as str from dataset
```